# Add two unicode methods to a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am using a custom model manager in addition to the default manager (`objects=model.Manager()`). I would like to add two `__unicode__` methods to the model -- one for the default manager and one for the custom manager; otherwise, the unicode throws an error for the result of the custom manager, which does not contain some of the variables used in the unicode for the default manager.

For example --

```
class CreditCountManager(models.Manager):
    def credit_count(self):
        ...
        return result_list

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network)
    ...
    credit_count = CreditCountManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

# need something like:
def __unicode-for-default__(self):
    return "%s(%s)"%(self.user, self.network)

def __unicode-for-credit_count__(self):
    return "%s(%s)"%(other variables)
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: "... the unicode throws an error for the result of the custom manager." ... What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not state what kind of error you have and thus is incomplete.

Unfortunately **unicode** is a Python construct. You can have just one off them.

Instead, you need to fix the place were the object is formatted to a string to use a custom method.

E.g.

```
 text = obj.my_formatter()
```

instead of

```
  text = u"Something " + obj
```

If the problem is an exception risen inside **unicode**() method you need to write the method in such a way that the exception does not occur. E.g. don't use uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `try/except` in the `__unicode__` method to simplify it:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    try:
        self.user
        return "%s(%s)"%(self.user, self.network)
    except (User.DoesNotExist, Network.DoesNotExist):
        return "%s(%s)"%(self.full_name, self.credit_count)
```